# Facebook returning The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action for half of the users

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an app that is public to the world (not dev mod).
I have 1000 users registered in the last 4 weeks with the permissions `email,publish_actions`.
The problem is, in the **first** attempt to post in their feed I got an error for **half** of them:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"FSQbqGwg8WC"}}
```

Why am I getting this for half , I dont think its related to code because half of them are ok.
I am not a spammer, this is the first attempt to publish something so it cant be that 500 remove them self from the app.

thanks